# How to delete particular contacts in recent call list in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, calllog

I have created a hash map with unique keys and their boolean value. In keys I am getting the row unique ID of callog.calls. What I want is that those keys who has corresponding true value will get deleted from recent call list in phone. I need to know how can I query and delete selected row from calllog.calls. I tried by myself but the code is not working

```
public void onclickhandler(View nn){
    boolean state=false;
    rl=(RelativeLayout) nn.getParent();
    TextView tv=(TextView)rl.getChildAt(1);
    cb=(CheckBox)rl.getChildAt(2);
    if(cb.isChecked()){
        state=true;
    }

    String s=tv.getText().toString();
    hmp.put(s, state);

    Log.i("value", tv.getText().toString());
    System.out.println(state);
} //...........
      //I want to delete the contacts on button click.here 
      //is the code for the listener..

done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                              null, null, null, null);
        Set keys = hmp.keySet();
        Iterator it=keys.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String keyvalue=(String) it.next();

            if(hmp.get(keyvalue).booleanValue()==true){
                try{
                    cur.moveToPosition(Integer.parseInt(keyvalue));
                    String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                                CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));

                    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                              CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, lookupKey);

                    System.out.println("The uri is " + uri.toString());
                    cr.delete(uri, null, null);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
                }
            }//if       
        }//while

    }//on click
});
```

Comment: are you storing these values in a database, why I am asking is bcoz you've said you will query them ?

Comment: no I have not created my own database .just want to delete them from android.provider.contacts db .

Comment: you can see the edited version.it is more clear on what I am actually trying to do

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> me:nameofHashMap.entrySet())

for(Entry<String, String> me:nameofHashMap.keySet())
```

use this statement to get the values you want and complete your code :)

me.getKey(); will get you all the values you need. "me" is the name of the object that you are creating, give it any name you want and call the object.

Comment: how to use this and where to put.I think the problem is still same.how should I query a single row from database.I think the problem is here at   cr.delete(uri, where, null)...I have not been able to figure out what to put in where argument.let say I have a row unique id i.e some number.how can i delete a complete row against some number.thanks for your reply any ways..

Comment: I am getting the values I need .the question is how to delete the whole row corresponding  that value.or what to put in where field in cr.delete(uri,where,null)...I have no clue how this method is working.